# Custom Jquery code in Magento2 not working

Tags: jquery, magento2

What I have done is to add a custom jquery code in a existing js file.

for example the contents of the file is like:

```
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

define([
    'uiComponent',
    'jquery',
    'ko',
    'underscore',
    'mage/translate',

],



 function (Component, $, ko, _) {
    'use strict';
    return Component.extend({
......
```

now in the end before the closing tag I have added line like

```
....
    updateNotifications: function(url){
            var self = this;
            $.getJSON(url,function(data){
                self.customData.percent(data.statistics.percent);
                self.customData.href(data.statistics.href);
                self.customData.contentLoading(0);
                self.customData.notifications(data.notifications);
                self.customData.vendor(data.vendor);

                setTimeout(function(){ self.updateNotifications(url); }, 60000);
            });
        }


   });

$("[data-index='painting_hieght']").hide(); //this the line added by me

});
```

I expect the field/label be hidden on load, but it doesn't.
I have tested the code in firebug console which works fine.

How I can integrate the cusotom jQuery code in a Magetno Js file.

**Update:**

I created a custom Js file named `myweb.js`
and placed it in the folder custom Module js folder.
and included the same in the related layout xml file.

The code I am using is like this:

```
require([
    "jquery"
    ], function($){
    $(document).ready(function() {
    alert("Hello");
    $("[data-index='painting_hieght']").hide();
    $("[name='product[size]']").change(function(){
     var status = this.value;
     alert(status);
   if(status=="103"){
      $("[data-index='painting_hieght'],[data-index='painting_width']").show();// hide multiple sections
        }else {
            $("[data-index='painting_hieght'],[data-index='painting_width']").hide();
        }
  });
    });
   });
```

I am getting the alert properly,

but rest of the code doesn't have any effect.
but the same code if I test in firebug console, it works fine.

Comment: Are you including this js file in  head? Try including it before the closing body tag

Comment: Yes. the file itself is named as `header.js`

Comment: I just observed that the file is included through `requirejs-config.js` and not in head of any xml file. could this be the reason, that the code is not working?

Comment: May be your DOM is not painted yet when the js gets included dynamically with require thats why your code isnt working. Try keeping a breakpoint on that line in js and see if you are getting any element in $("[data-index='painting_hieght']").

Comment: @NanditaAroraSharma - I have updated the question, if you can have a look. as regarding the alert, I am getting it only first time after cleaning cache, but subsequent reload, even the alert is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Please write code in magetno jquery tag like

```
 require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){ 
     //your js code here  
 });
```

in your case, you only use jquery but magetno also need jquery/ui. You can also use in any phtml file. Please try this.

Thanks